# How to run ajax every time I hover with a scroll plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, smooth-scrolling

When I wasn't using the plugin to put ajax content into my scroll div, I could do this

```
$('.album').hover(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    ajax request here
});
```

And every time I would hover over .album with a new id a different set of content would be the input specific to the id number. But I have to use the plugin to use ajax because it has to do other functions for the scroll to work.

So I try this:

```
$('.album').hover(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
             getContentOnLoad: { 
             method: "getAjaxContent",
             content: "albumphotos.php?id="+ id,
             manipulationMethod: "replace"
             }
        });
});
```

Which works perfect and lets the scroll work. But then I scroll over to a different album with a different id it doesn't redo the request and stays with the same id and same content. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize the plugin outside the hover function and use the public method `getAjaxContent` to replace the content:

```
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll();
// add the getContentOnLoad option if you need to get some content on page load

$('.album').hover(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("getAjaxContent", "albumphotos.php?id="+ id, "replace");
});
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot about this... wow thanks a ton Ive spent way too much time on this. If anyone wants more info http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/publicMethods.html#getAjaxContent

Comment: @user2127833 glad to help, as a rule of thumb you shouldn't try to initialize a plugin in an element multiple times (unless you destroy it every time) as you were doing in your hover function, most plugins should provide a way to call a method or update the options